# How to override controllers in cs-cart

Tags: php, cs-cart

Sometimes you need to override default controller behavior in cs-cart. But you can't use `override` modifier like in hooks.

What are approaches we can use to override default controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach I found is to use `dispatch_assign_template` hook from `fn.control.php` file.

1. define hook in your addon's `init.php` file.
2. add next function in your addon's `func.php` file

```
function fn_myaddon_dispatch_assign_template($controller, $mode, $area, &$controllers_cascade) {
    if ($controller !== 'categories' || $mode !== 'view') {
        return;
    }

    //excluded default categories controller 
    $default_controller_path  = DIR_ROOT . '/app/controllers/frontend/categories.php';
    
    $controllers_cascade = array_filter(
        $controllers_cascade,
        static function ($item) use ($default_controller_path) {
            return $default_controller_path !== $item;
        }
    );
}
```

- We passed `&$controllers_cascade` parameter by reference.
- We excluded default controller from `$controllers_cascade` array.

3. Add your own controller like `categories.post.php` and add

```
if ($mode == 'view') {
    //your code here.
}
```